# MongoDB Mongoose state persistence

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

When you do this in a `main.js` module:

```
var db = require('mongoose');
db.connect('mongodb://localhost/piautomation');
var myOwnModule = require('./myOwnModule');
```

And `myOwnModule.js`:

```
var db = require('mongoose');
```

Is `db` using a persisted mongoose connection or do you have to wrap the `mongoose` module in your own module to persist the connection?

Below is the wrapped version.

`main.js` code:

```
var dbConnect = require('./dbConnect'),
    myOwnModule = require('./myOwnModule');
```

`dbConnect.js` code:

```
var db = require('mongoose');
module.exports = db.connect('mongodb://localhost/piautomation');
```

`myOwnModule.js` code:

```
var persistedDb = require('./dbConnect');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to do that.

On application start up, you can do the following:

```
var db = require('mongoose');
db.connect('mongodb://localhost/piautomation');
```

Connections are pooled internally by mongoose

From the [Mongoose Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

> Each connection, whether created with mongoose.connect or mongoose.createConnection are all backed by an internal configurable connection pool defaulting to a size of 5.

Comment: so what does that mean then, i just do `var db = require('mongoose')` in any module and it will pick the connection i've just made?

Comment: yes, as long as you've created the connection first